# Vertical Scroll doesn't work with Keyboard arrow up/down

Tags: jsf-2, scroll, richfaces, picklist

I'm using RichFaces 4.3.5 and when I try to select an option on picklist with keyboard arrow up and down the options focus change but the scroll do not follow.

For example, there are 20 options, you can see 10. I use the arrow and pass by one by one. When I got the 11º position, the scroll doesn't move, so I cant see the 11º.

I don't know if I was clear enough... but this also happens in richfaces showcase.

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList&skin=blueSky

Try to see the others options with keyboard, the scroll dosn't move.

Does anyone know how can I fix this? Any workaround?

Thank you verymuch

this is how I'm using.

```
<rich:pickList value="#{filter.subItemsSelected}" listHeight="75" styleClass="#{filter.codigo} hide" addAllText="Adicionar todos" addText="Adicionar" removeAllText="Remover todos" removeText="Remover">
    <f:selectItems value="#{filter.subItems}" var="sub" itemValue="#{sub}" itemLabel="#{sub.nome}" />
    <f:converter converterId="filtroConverter" />
</rich:pickList>
```

Comment: It seems there is a bug, it should scroll but the scroll method is called on the wrong element.

Comment: @Makhiel do you have any idea how could I make this? Using jquery maybe...

Comment: You'd need to add a listener for `keyup` and scroll the list - if you check the code it's implemented in there (list.js) but it is scrolling the wrong the element.